# WooCommerce reorder account passwort field on checkout

Tags: php, woocommerce

I try to reorder the WooCommerce account password field on the checkout page with the code below. However, it creates a new field but does not move the account password field.

I followed the instructions from that page here: https://jeroensormani.com/ultimate-guide-to-woocommerce-checkout-fields/#sorting-checkout-fields

How can I reorder the account password filed on WooCommerce checkout?

**Goal:** The Account password field should be after the email field.

```
function js_sort_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['account_password']['priority'] = 111;

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'js_sort_checkout_fields' );
```

Answer (score 0):

We was able to solve it.

```
function move_password_field($checkout_fields){
    // Move Account Password into Billing
    $checkout_fields['billing']['account_password'] = $checkout_fields['account']['account_password']; 

    // Remove Password from Billing
    unset($checkout_fields['account']['account_password']);

    return $checkout_fields;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'move_password_field', 999);
```